# Setting the Properties of the Default Printer in windows through C#

Tags: c#, printing

I want to change the settings of Default printer in C#(e.g Copies,Page Size,From - To Pages etc.)

Comment: Consider retagging your question.  Although this may pertain to homework, you're going to get better results from the people who follow [c#] or [.net]

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to check out the documentation on the [PrinterSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.aspx) Class. This class has properties for [Copies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.copies.aspx), [Paper Sizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.papersizes.aspx), and [Print Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.printrange.aspx), (the settings you specified) among many others.

The [System.Drawing.Printing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.aspx) Namespace page also provides a decent amount of information related to printing.