# Set default Printer Page size using C#

Tags: c#, windows, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting the Properties of the Default Printer in windows through C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819311/setting-the-properties-of-the-default-printer-in-windows-through-c-sharp)

I wanna set custom page size in the default printer in windows using C#, and these changes must be set as default to print using them later. i have tried to change the page size for A3 just alter its size but in vain.

`PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("A3", 100 , 100);`

Any help please.

Comment: Try having a look at this link here: [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819311/setting-the-properties-of-the-default-printer-in-windows-through-c-sharp). A person has asked the same question.

Comment: the answer of that question is not accurate anymore

Comment: @geogeek In whats sense is that not accurate? Are you on .Net 5.0?